# Pseudorandom Generator Expansion

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I have a question regarding the theoretic definition of Pseudorandom Generators. In [Katz & Lindell's textbook (2nd edition)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html), Definition 3.14 (p. 62), it is defined as follows:

> **DEFINITION 3.14.** Let $\ell$ be a polynomial and let $G$ be a deterministic polynomial-time algorithms such that for any $n$ and any input $ \in \{0,1\}^n$, the result $G(s)$ is a string of length $\ell(n)$. We say that $G$ is a **pseudorandom generator** if the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. **(Expansion:)** For every $n$ it holds that $\ell(n) > n$.
> 2. **(Pseudorandomness:)** For any PPT algorithm $D$, there is a negligible function $\mathsf{negl}$ such that $$\bigg|\mathrm{Pr}\big[D(G(s)) = 1\big] - \mathrm{Pr}\big[D(r) = 1\big]\bigg| ≤ \mathsf{negl}(n)$$ where thre first probability is taken over uniform choice of $s \in \{0,1\}^n$ and the randomness of $D$, and **the second probability is taken over uniform choice of $r \in \{0,1\}^{\ell(n)}$** and the randomness of $D$.

**My Question:** Why is **Expansion** necessary? I mainly don't understand why it is not defined as $l(n) \geq n$, therefore why is $l(n) = n$ not included?

Comment: If you can get only $n$ from $n$ bit why do you use PRG?

Comment: By intuition I would include $l(n)=n$ and define **Expansion** as $l(n) \geq n$. My question is, why they did not do it, and defined it as $l(n) > n$ instead.

Comment: I think the reason for the $l(n)>n$ requirement is to make existence of a PRG non-trivial (notice that with $l(n)\ge n$, identity is a PRG). It avoids the need to add _", if $l(n)>n$"_ to statements like _existence of a PRG implies the existence of a (insert crypto smurf)_.